# Can depth peeling be implemented without any shader?

Tags: opengl, transparency, depth

I don't know shaders, but I have a basic idea of their concept.

I need to implement depth peeling and so I would like to know if first I should go deeper into the shader world or it could be implemented without shaders, just using smartly the glDepthFunc..

Comment: Using opengl 4.x core profile, you have to specify shaders! glDepthFunc just configures the depth comparision function.. Depth peeling methods usually require multi pass rendering .. so definitely write some shaders first.. but you don't have to go deep into the shader world to write an effect :)

Comment: The sooner you start working with shaders, the better. Even if you keep it simple, you can do some really amazing stuff. Decide what GLSL version to learn first. GLSL 1.50 and higher recommended.

Comment: Ok guys, if it seems like there is no other way, then I will go with shaders.. Just a question, since I am using right now opengl 2.x, this means GLSL 1.10.. should I also upgrade and use some late opengl or I can fully implement a depth peeling with opengl 2.x?

Comment: You can use GLSL 1.2, but might as well do it properly and at least aim for GLSL/GL 3.3. A lot of stuff is deprecated, but you still have backwards compatibility. (Unless you are on OS X being stuck at GL 3.2 core only profile)

Comment: Ok, some good place to start from with GLSL 3.3 for my intent? I guess books are too much, arent they? The GL wiki should be enough for me? http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: [This book/tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html) uses OpenGL 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it if you have GL_ARB_depth_texture & GL_ARB_shadow, although it is fiddly.

GL_ARB_occlusion_query is very useful as well, as it allows you to decide when to stop peeling.  If you don't have this then you can still do it, but need a fixed number of iterations through your loop.  Too high and you waste time & memory, too low and you may introduce visual artifacts.

This code is hacked out of some test code I used to debug some depth peeling algorithms a while ago.  I have ripped out all the system specific stuff, replaced it with pseudocode & done some restructuring so don't expect it to compile.  Hopefully you should be able to get the idea.

For order independent transparency using this approach you would probably create a list of depth textures, then traverse in reverse order.

[code]
    bool DrawNthSurface(size_t passes)
    {
        GLboolean cached_stencil_test_enabled;
        GLboolean cached_alpha_test_enabled;
        GLboolean cached_depth_test_enabled;
        GLboolean cached_face_cull_enabled;

```
    glGetBooleanv(GL_STENCIL_TEST, &cached_stencil_test_enabled);
    glGetBooleanv(GL_ALPHA_TEST, &cached_alpha_test_enabled);
    glGetBooleanv(GL_DEPTH_TEST, &cached_depth_test_enabled);
    glGetBooleanv(GL_CULL_FACE, &cached_face_cull_enabled);

    if(HasShadow()) // Checks GL_ARB_shadow
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else
    {
        GLuint depthTexture(0);

        bool status(true);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);

        // Draw geometry into the depth buffer.  No textures, shaders etc.
        //
        // This could easily be folded into next part by restructuring into 
        // do...while()
        status&= DrawSimpleGeometry();

        if(status)
        {
            // for transparency etc. you would build a list of these inside the 
            // loop.  For finding the nth surface we can recycle one.
            glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);

            if(depthTexture)
            {
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);

                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                             GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 
                             ctx->GetViewportWidth(), 
                             ctx->GetViewportHeight(), 0,
                             GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);


                // Set up texture unit.
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                                GL_NEAREST);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                                GL_NEAREST);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                                GL_CLAMP);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                                GL_CLAMP); 

                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

                // Set up texture coord generation.  Should get bias from depth buffer 
                // precision.
                SetupTexGen(-0.004);

                // Set up shadow test.

                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                                GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE_ARB, 
                                        GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE_ARB);

                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                                GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC_ARB, 
                                GL_GREATER);

                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                                GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE_ARB, 
                                GL_ALPHA);

                glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.5f);
                glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST); 

                for(size_t n=0;(n<passes) && status;n++)
                {
                    // Update depth texture.
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
                    glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                        ctx->GetViewportWidth(), 
                                        ctx->GetViewportHeight());


                    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                    status&= DrawSimpleGeometry();
                }

                // deactivate shadow test.
                {
                    // Texgen
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

                    // Texture unit
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

                    // Shadow comparison
                    glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST); 
                }

                glDeleteTextures(1, &depthTexture);
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }

        // Restore some of the rendering state.
        if(cached_face_cull_enabled)
        {
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        }
        else
        {
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        }

        glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);

        if(cached_face_cull_enabled)
        {
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        }
        else
        {
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        }

        if(!cached_stencil_test_enabled)
        {
            glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        }
        else
        {
            glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        }

        if(!cached_alpha_test_enabled)
        {
            glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        }
        else
        {
            glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        }

        if(!cached_depth_test_enabled)
        {
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
        else
        {
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }

        // FINALLY: Draw everything.
        if(status)
        {
            glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);
            status&= DrawAllGeometry();
        }

        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

        return status;
    }
}
```

[/code]

IMHO the trickiest bit is getting the texgen set up correctly.  The code is pretty simple.  I have included a bias parameter to avoid z fighting artifacts.

[code]
    Matrix CreateTextureMatrix(double bias)
    {
        Matrix projection, cmay;

```
    double tmp[16];

    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, tmp);

    projection = Matrix(tmp);

    Matrix bias_matrix(0.5, 0.0, 0.0,        0.0,
                       0.0, 0.5, 0.0,        0.0,
                       0.0, 0.0, 0.5,        0.0,
                       0.5, 0.5, 0.5 + bias, 1.0);


    return (projection * bias_matrix);
}

void SetupTexGen(double bias)
{
    Matrix texmat;
    Matrix mv, imv;

    {
        double tmp[16];
        glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, tmp);
        mv = Matrix(tmp);

        imv = mv.GetInverse();
    }

    glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
    glTexGendv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, imv.Row(0));
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);

    glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
    glTexGendv(GL_T, GL_EYE_PLANE, imv.Row(1));
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

    glTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
    glTexGendv(GL_R, GL_EYE_PLANE, imv.Row(2));
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);

    glTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
    glTexGendv(GL_Q, GL_EYE_PLANE, imv.Row(3));
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

    texmat = CreateTextureMatrix(bias);

    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMultMatrixd(texmat);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

[/code]

HTH.